# I have a problem when I want to customize my new button in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, syntax-error

I have this error in my code when I create `myButton` in Kotlin.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please first use the code format for your codes. Also, try to be **understandable** in your questions (The title). About the question, how about extending the Button to an `AppCompatButton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button` is a Function, not a class extended. Just make an function in `MainActivity`

**For example**

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MyButton()  // this is how to make button inside function

    }

    private fun MyButton(){

     // you can put your button listener here
     // example :

     mMyBtn.setOnClickListener {
            // and then put ur logic here
            Toast.makeText(this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }
}
```

**or maybe try below**

```
class MyButton : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context!!, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context!!, attrs, defStyle)

    protected override fun onDraw(canvasObject: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvasObject)
    }
}
```

let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: How do you know they don't need to subclass Button?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it a warning, not an error. Your code will still run fine. But the reason for this warning/suggestion is because `AppCompatButton` is part of `androidx` library also comes with backward support for some features , they are also tint aware meaning it allows dynamic and background tints.

From the documentation of [AppCompatButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatButton)

> A Button which supports compatible features on older versions of the platform, >including:
>
> - Allows dynamic tint of its background via the background tint methods
>   in ViewCompat.
> - Allows setting of the background tint using
>   R.attr.backgroundTint and R.attr.backgroundTintMode.
> - Allows setting of the font family using R.attr.fontFamily.
> - This will automatically be
>   used when you use Button in your layouts and the top-level activity /
>   dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use
>   this class when writing custom views.

From above, When ever you use a `Button`, it automatically uses `AppCompatButton`, so you should take care of extending `AppCompatButton` in custom views to get most of it.